# Using oauth with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twitter, oauth

I am creating a twitter plugin for wordpress and I was told that when using oauth you can't really make the plugin act natively because each time the user installs the plugin they have to add their own twitter api credentials because of the callback url.  Is this correct?  Or is there a workaround for this?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Any number of Twitter plugins use oauth; they would be good to check out for the necessary code and techniques: [WordPress › Twitter WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=twitter&sort=)